# Javascript module not loading in HTML in Chrome v91

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, es6-modules

I have a simple javascript module containing classes common to my browser side javascript and node server ES6 modules.  The code is all same origin so there are no load errors but none of the exported entities from the ES6 module are available in the browser script.
Ignoring reuse and considering just the Browser side, this works:
**latlong.js** non-module

```
function LatLon(lat,lon) {
      this.lat = lat;
      this.lon = lon;
  }
```

**test.html**

```
<body>
  <script  src="latlong.js"></script>
  <script>
    let test = new LatLon(1,2)
  </script>
</body>
```

But this does not use modules and therefore not sharable with Node server code so *I want the following to work but it fails*
**latlong.js** module that imports fine in server side Node js code and works

```
export class LatLon {
    constructor(lat, lon) {
      this.lat = lat;
      this.lon = lon;
    }
  }
```

**test.html** with module import

```
<body>
  <script type="module" src="latlong.js"></script>
  <script>
    let test = new LatLon(1,2)  <=Uncaught ReferenceError: LatLon is not defined
  </script>
</body>
```

There are many other variations on how to export a class/prototype from the module or declare a prototype class but all result in the same error for me.

This is running in a local webserver and I've verified the headers returned in both cases for loading latlong.js has content-type *application/javascript*.  Since this is an ampps web server I can change the mime type for js and mjs requests to text/javascript to be more compliant but this has no effect on the error reported.

Including a module in an HTML document is common so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Modules won't work if you dont `import` them where you want to use them.
Also you have to declare the importing `script` as a `module` one.

This will work:

```
<script type="module">
  import {LatLon} from 'latlong.js';
  let test = new LatLon(1,2)
</script>
```

Comment: Sadly this still isn't working as expected but thank you @Guerric P for looking at this. Apologies up front for the attempt to show example code here but line breaks are not supported in comments :(.      The 'import' statement only is in scope for that `<script type="module">` block.  For example the second reference again reports "Reference Error: LatLon xx" 
`<script type="module">
      import {LatLon} from "./latlong.js"
 let test = new LatLon(1,2)
  </script>
  <script>
      let test2 = new LatLon(3,4)
  </script>`   same error occurs if the 2nd <script type="module"> is used.

Answer (score 0):

I was successful adding the import line to every  block that needed the contents but I don't like it.  Maybe some experts can explain why this is "better"?

```
<script type="module">
  import {LatLon} from 'latlong.js'; //import where first used (not in <HEAD>)
  let test = new LatLon(1,2)
</script>
```

... later on page ...

```
<script type="module">
  import {LatLon} from 'latlong.js';  //required to import module again
  let test2 = new LatLon(1,2)
</script>
```

this means you are importing/including the same module throughout your html page and not once at the top of the file as is normal common practice. I don't know for sure if expecting all includes at the top of the file is best practice but I am quite used to this pattern and not ever expecting to look through code to find new dependencies.
My goal was for good coding practice and to share some global structs and enums between client and server.  Although the sharing is achieved along with the benefit of eliminating duplicate definitions in the code, this need to re-import seems to be a trade-off.
I know some will say "just put all your script in one block" and for me I find that is the case most of the time anyway. But the standard allows multiple  blocks for a reason and when you need it its there.  In EJS its encouraged.